# Unsupported column datatype from the user-defined type

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, user-defined-types, oracle-manageddataaccess

I don't know what I am missing for the ManagedDataAccess to complain about "Unsupported column datatype".  I love how the error does not point out what type or what "column" is giving it grief.  Can someone review the code below and let me know what did I miss?  Thank you very much!

The table

```
CREATE TABLE "PORTAL_OPS"."SHAPE" 
(   
 "SIDES" NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
)
```

The type

```
create or replace type shapeudt as object 
( 
  sides number(1,0)
)
```

The class

```
[OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("PORTAL_OPS.SHAPEUDT")]
public class Shape : IOracleCustomType, IOracleCustomTypeFactory
{
    [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("SIDES")]
    public Int32 sides;


    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "SIDES", sides);
    }
    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        sides = (int)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "SIDES");
    }

    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new Shape();
    }
}
```

Calling the UDT to the procedure:

```
// setting up the parameter
OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
//param.UdtTypeName         = udt.DatabaseTypeName;
param.DbType = DbType.Object;
// this needs to stay at the end...if you move it ahead of the
// previous line, you will get 
// "Value does not fall within the expected range" error
param.Value = udt;

Command.CommandText = "portal_ops.PROC_CREATE_SHAPE";
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Command.Parameters.Add(param);

if (Command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    Command.Connection.Open();
}

Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Command.Dispose();

Command.Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

**Cause:** 
Not using the right OracleDbType.  For the UDT, you HAVE to use OracleDbType.Object when you are defining the OracleParameter.  If you are like me, trying to be a fan of Oracle's Managed Driver.  Well, you are SOL, because the as of version 19.6, Oracle Managed Data Access Nuget still does not support OracleDbType.Object.

**Solution:**
Switch to the Unmanaged Driver.  Yes, you'll have to break up w/ the Managed Driver.
Down the VS tool from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdev-downloads.html).  Yes, the twist is you HAVE to use the one installed by Oracle Universal Installer (OUI).